# PHP: SimpleHTMLDom - Help me get the html page code?

Tags: php, html

who can help me implement getting html code from this page https://investmint.ru? I'm using the "SimpleHTMLDom" library, but something goes wrong and I get an empty response. Although other sites work fine with this code. What's wrong? Who can suggest or give advice?

```
include("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");

$url = "https://investmint.ru";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
echo $html;
```

I will be glad for any decision, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I get an empty response...Although other sites work fine with this code

I couldn't be bothered setting up the library, so I ran this....

```
print file_get_contents('https://investmint.ru');
```

I got this....

```
<html><head><script>function set_cookie(){var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();time += 19360000 * 1000;now.setTime(time);
document.cookie='beget=begetok'+'; expires='+now.toGMTString()+';
path=/';}set_cookie();location.reload();;</script></head><body></body></html>
```

I suspect you got the same but didn't investigate it properly.

Try it with the cookie. And learn how to use web developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Wow! You are really right! I figured out your help. But you can tell me how to pass a cookie in the request Cookies(beget = begetok)?

Comment: Simple html dom doesn't let you set cookies while scraping. I suggest that you use phantomjs. https://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/cookies.html